# How to make user email unique based on user roles

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel i am using laravel 6x.
Now i want to know how to make user email unique based on user roles .I am using spatie permissions
I have two type of users

- admin
- End user

Now i want to use laravel validation for same email for different roles,that means, email should be unique by roles.
Anybody has any idea, please let me know

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it is done, i have created a custom rule